# Class belonging to either of two?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How should I solve this relation between objects:

Object1 & Object2 are similiar "parent objects"

Object3 may be a child to Object1 or Object2.

How is this relation called and how should I code this in Grails?

Comment: E.g. how do I handle multiple belongsTo, while every object instance should only have 1?

Answer (score 1):

as I've found after asking this question:

I can have multiple belongsTo, 
just need to mark them nullable & check that only 1 of them are actually null.
In my case,:

```
static belongsTo = [obj1: Object1, obj2: Object2];
static constraints = {
    obj1(nullable: true, validator: {field, inst -> inst.obj2 || field})
    obj2(nullable: true)
}
```